# Format jQuery UI datepicker with Canadian format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't seem to get my dates formatted properly. In Canada, we serve our dates up dd/MM/yyyy

When I render my textbox to hold a date, it is emited like this:

```
<input type="date" value="18/03/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
```

I know if I add the datepicker to this textbox and then add a format, the contents of the text box will be deleted. So I save the value of the textbox, apply the datepicker, apply the format, and then set the date:

```
var datepicker_default_val = $(this).val();
$(this).datepicker();
$(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');
$(this).datepicker("setDate", datepicker_default_val);
```

However, when I set the date, the textbox value is registering as 24-10-2018.

Anyone know how I can make my Canadian date and the datepicker play nice?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

i found a site (http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?170104-Getting-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-javascript) where the solution was to code it using variables like so;

```
 var curr_date = date.getDate();
 var curr_month = date.getMonth();
 curr_month = curr_month + 1;
 var curr_year = date.getFullYear();

 // Now i can get my required date in my desired format. For Example,
 date= curr_date + '/'+ curr_month + '/'+ curr_year;
```

i do the same when coding dates. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you should change this line:

```
var datepicker_default_val = $(this).val();
```

to this

```
var datepicker_default_val = new Date($(this).val());
```